# Reading two separate CSV files

Tags: netlogo

Currently I am struggling to get my netlogo to read two different ckv files to set my global variables. I got two files that needs to read every tick. See my code so far:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  file-close-all ;; Close any files open from last run
  file-open "oil price.csv"
  file-open "co2 price.csv"
  setup-patches
  create-industries 25
  ask industries [set shape "house"]
  ask industries [set color red]
  ask industries [move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = green] ]
  ask industries [set oil-demand 1 + random-float 9]

  create-ports 1
  ask ports [set shape "pentagon"]
  ask ports [set color yellow]
  ask ports [setxy 0 0]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if file-at-end? [ stop ]
  set oil-price csv:from-file "oil price.csv"
  set co2-price csv:from-file "co2 price.csv"
  ;; model update goes here
  if ticks = length "oil price.csv" [stop]
  tick
end
```

I managed to have it read one csv for oil-price and change its variable every tick. However, adding another does not work. I want to have a separate csv for oil price that changes each tick and the same for co2 price. I am missing something? I am new to netlogo by the way. All help appreciated! Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

My recollection is that the csv extension reads from the most recently opened file.  So, if you put each `file-open` statement just before the respective command to read from the file, it should alternate between them.

```
file-open "oil price.csv"
set oil-price csv:from-file "oil price.csv"
file-open "co2 price.csv"
set co2-price csv:from-file "co2 price.csv"
```